# Why Float is better than position:relative and absolute while we can make layout quickly with position?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Why Float is better than position:relative and absolute while we can make layout quickly with position? and in this recession time,  time is very important.

when we make 2-col, 3-col or multi-col layout and then position other elements in layout divs.

Most of the world favor in Float . Why Float is better than `position:relative` and `position:absolute` to give position any element in `<body>` and other nested elements?

If using position: to layout a page/design, we can create a container div which is set to position:relative, allowing header, content and nav `divs` inside the container div to be set to position:relative, allowing these `divs` to be positioned relative to the container div.

and with positioning we can keep `"maincontent"` first and `"leftsidebar"` second in source order which is good for SEO.

**please explain things with example demo page**.

Comment: The question is not consistent/clear. There is no comparison between "float" and "position relative/absolute". A float requires positioning (either declared or inherited), and in addition, there are other positioning types such as static and fixed.

Comment: Tell you what: why don’t *you* give us a demo page of a specific layout done using `position: relative;` and `absolute`, and we’ll see if `float` would give any benefit to it. Your question is general, whereas choosing one CSS property over another depends on the details of the specific layout you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Below answers are either theoretical or given examples are wrong, because one has to imagine browser as a 3D container, before understanding `float` property.I think [this](http://youtube.com/watch?v=xara4Z1b18I) is one good explanation on CSS float property. `float:right` works parallel to x-axis in 3d view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` will not break the document flow -- also, it will position any element it uses the best it can fit in the container width -- say I have 5 x 200px divs in a 800px width container, the last 5th will go in a "new line" below the other ones -- using `position:relative` will make you need to calculate when it needs to break yourself, and it won't break correctly since the `display` will either be `block` and go over the whole width or it will be `inline-block` or `inline` which won't render the same way for divs as `block` would and would pretty much mess up the document flow & layout.

It depends on what you want to do: `position:relative` is used to move the element a bit aside from it's natural location, whereas `float` will make it pop to the left-most or right-most position in the parent element. `position:absolute` will let you position it relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Comment: "`position:absolute` will let you position it relatively to the whole html document." Incorrect, `position:absolute` lets you position the element "relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element". You can perfectly use it to offset the element from its parent, if that parent has something like a position:relative (even without any offsets).

Answer (score 18):

Absolute positioning *takes the element out of the normal document flow*. Any absolutely positioned element is completely ignored when regarding normal elements.

This breaks in a lot of scenarios. The main one that springs to mind is putting elements underneath each other. With your column example, sure you can absolutely position 3 columns, but you can't put anything below that on the page, because the flow is still at the top of the page. The "absolute" elements do not affect where later content comes.

With floats, you just put an element afterwards and it wraps around or underneath the floating ones.

That's not to say it has no use. Positioning is very useful when you want to pop up a "layer" over the web page.

---

A short example... take this common HTML scenario:

```
<h2>Section title</h2>
<div class="column1">First</div>
<div class="column2">Second</div>
<div class="column3">Third</div>

<h2>Second section title</h2>
...
```

With floats, you'd use this CSS:

```
.column1, .column2, .column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
h2 {
  clear: both;
}
```

And everything would be fine. Let's absolutely position the columns instead:

```
.column1, .column2, .column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 30px; /* enough to miss the first h2 */
}
.column1 {
  left: 0;
  background: pink;
}
.column2 {
  left: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.column3 {
  left: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Try this for yourself (with more content in each column) and see what happens to the second heading - it will always be right under the first one, as if the columns aren't there. Actually, the second heading would be mostly hidden by the columns since they're layered over the top of the document.

Unless the columns are fixed height then it is impossible to know where to put that heading below the columns. It's even worse if you want more columns under each heading.

Honestly, just give it a try and attempt a nice layout using absolute positioning. You'll soon understand its failings.

Comment: can u explain ur answer with live example

Comment: @Jit: example posted, give it a try.

Comment: but you are using position:absolute for column put all html code in <div id="container"> and give position:relative to #container

Comment: @Jit: Not sure I understand you. Wrapping the HTML in that code does absolutely nothing, you still can't put content below the columns. Like I and others have stated, absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal document flow (even if it has a relative parent), so all content that isn't in those columns acts as if the columns aren't there at all.

Comment: Hey this is wrong example with `position` property, because *relative(or static) positioned elements don't decide their own height*. This is why second header is going below columns. Bad example.

Comment: @overexchange yes and their height cannot be determined because the content inside them is absolutely positioned, which is the reason position is bad for layouts. If you disagree, please provide a good example.

Comment: First thing is, If you make an element absolutely positioned, then better make it with reference to some parent element(relative/absolute). why would you make an absolutely positioned element in reference to `body` in your example?

Comment: @overexchange Why does that matter? You have the same problems if you use a relative positioned div instead of body. The question is about using positioning for layout - with absolute positioning you can't position elements below other elements because their height cannot be determined. (Again: please provide a better example.)

Answer (score 4):

Float is not better than Position, and Position is not better than Float - both should be used in the correct situation. I would recommend you read the book http://www.transcendingcss.com/ if you want to learn more about when to use which one, and CSS styling in general.

See here for an example: http://transcendingcss.com/blog/about/changingman_layout_updated/

Comment: i've already read this book and see this article http://www.wardontheweb.com/float-vs-position-in-layout-my-gripe-with-andy-clarke/

Comment: That article you link to proves my point perfectly - it's all down to the personal preference of the designer/coder - there is no right or wrong answer - there are just ones that work and ones that don't :)

Answer (score 3):

Absolute : your element is positioned to the first parent element with a position other than static (it must be explicit, even if the default position is relative)

Relative : your element is positioned to its last sibling with a relative position

Float : for instance if it's left, your element will move as far as it can to the left (depending on other element and its width, the elements before won't be affected, the elements after will flow around it.

Ref:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: and float is also like position:relative.

Comment: It's two things absolutely different, one is positioning and the other is floating. Don't mix everything.

Answer (score 2):

we use `float` as `absolute` positioning does not work for variable height columns.

When you specify `position:absolute`, the element is removed from the document and placed exactly where you tell it to go

If you specify `position:relative`, then you can use top or bottom, and left or right to move the element relative to where it would normally occur in the document.

Source: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Absolute positioning does work for variable height columns, as long as the parent has relative positioning.

Comment: will the relative positioned div content be not overwritten by absolute positioned div?

Answer (score 1):

i agree with Frozenskys, neither are actually better but *float* keeps the element within the document flow while *position* removes the element from the document flow, so i've found *float* works better across more browsers and my IE specific CSS is smaller when i use *float*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it’s not a general better/worse issue, but:

Absolute positioning removes an element from the document’s flow. The element given absolute positioning will no longer affect the layout of other elements in the document.

As such, it’s usually not the right choice for doing an entire page layout unless you know what the width and height of all your content is going to be.

Comment: so if we know width and height and content not going to be changed then no problem using position

Comment: Pretty much. Your question is a bit general. It’s a bit like asking: “Which is better? `margin` or `text-indent`”? It depends what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your purposes, it may be better or worse. The good side is that it doesn't change the positioning mechanism. The bad side is that you can't do some tricks (i.e. element overlapping) with it. Float is only good for attaching an element to either edge of a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old string but here goes: I found that when I have complete information on the nature and amount of content, and the nature and amount of content tends to not change, then positioning attributes give me more control over my layout appearance. If the nature and amount of content needs more flexibility due to frequent changes, then float will give me that flexibility, but does not generally give me as much control over appearance.

I don't always need the precision of positioning but I'm glad it's there when I do need it.

Of course, it also depends upon how well you know your html/css and how much time you are willing to spend coding in order to get around the limitations for one attribute or another.

For example, `<h2>` gives  you a large bold heading title understood by all browsers, but you can do the same thing with `<p>` if you are willing to add the styling attributes to make your bold heading to designed specifics. It's more work, mostly unnecessary, but can be done.

Generally, it's better to do as little coding as possible, using established elements, attributes and values, and as few hacks as possible. That is the point behind the HTML5 standards. Use positioning when you need it, but use float when you can.

Great site. Good contributors. I learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**None of both is suitable for creating layouts.**

- Floats are meant to be used in images that you want the text to wrap around.
- Position absolute is meant to place elements with some kind of x and y coordinates.

Floats were used 10 years ago to create layouts, but not anymore because using floats for layouts is hacky. Floats are not meant to be used to create layouts, but at that time, it was better than tables. And now they are outdated.

Nowadays, if you want to make a layout you should use **CSS Grid**, that's what it's meant for. Check this article to learn how to use it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

This is an example of how to use CSS Grid:

```css
.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem auto;
}

/* Not relevant */
body {margin:0;}
.grid-1 > div,
.grid-2 > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
h2 {margin: 1.5rem 0 0.5rem;}
.bg-red {background: tomato;}
.bg-blue {background: royalblue;}
.bg-green {background: lightgreen;}
.bg-yellow {background: khaki;}
```

```html
<h2>Example grid 1</h2>
<div class="grid-1">
  <div class="bg-red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="bg-blue">The remaining space gets filled.</div>
</div>

<h2>Example grid 2</h2>
<div class="grid-2">
  <div class="bg-green">Fixed width column</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div>The page continues...</div>
```