# Boxes are overlapping in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know this is probably very simple but I cannot find a solution. Basically in my CSS my boxes are overlapping. My website needs to be responsive and when I shrink the browser window down the boxes start overlapping. They do not overlap normally, only when I shrink the window and they start overlapping more and more the smaller I make it. I don't really know how to fix it and I need help please.The two boxes that are overlapping are content-box1 and content-left
Code:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    background: #394BA0;
    color:#C180E4;
    border-color:#88C6ED;
}
#wrapper {
    width:62.7%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    height: 1199px;
    position: abosulte;
}
#header{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
}
#content-left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    margin-top: 15%;
    position: absolute;
}
#content-main {
    position: absolute;
}
#content-box1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 26%;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: absolute;
}
#content-box2 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 26%;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left:21%;
    position: absolute;
}
#content-box3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 26%;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left:42%;
    position: absolute;
}
#bottom {
    width: 27%;
    height: 27%;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    position: absoulte;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: **position: absolute; + responsive = deep headhache!** In the meanwhile, can you provide a live example so there is enough to analyse and help you.

Comment: I personally would just use something like Bootstrap which takes the headache of responsive sites out of the frame. p.s Post your HTML markup and a link if possible, you will get more help that way.

Comment: @MilchePatern he's using Dreamweaver ... Headache X Infinity!

Comment: floats are more reliable than positions are -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317219/why-float-is-better-than-positionrelative-and-absolute-while-we-can-make-layout

Comment: Greetings user user3150475 and welcome 'again' to stackoverflow. You are strongly invited to read 'again' the faq and take the tour so you can understand why anyone will be able to help you. Lack of informations about your html will need a divination to figure out what's not working. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting all of the positions to absolute. If you change the size of the window the positions won't change relative to the window. I would recommend using the 'float' property, it's much more flexible and can do basically the same thing.

Read more:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
and:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Best wishes.